# How the "jQuery Dialog" anchor with a marker in google map? Like info window I wish to use the jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery

## I wish to add JQuery Dialog in Google panorama street view.

```
var markerSample = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng),
            map: panorama
         });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerSample, 'click', function () {
    var dialogMine = $("#mySampleDialogBox").dialog(); });
```

Here I can Add the Dialog on the map. Want to set an anchor with marker or set a LATLNG position for our Dialog

Comment: so what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: question not clear, what have ltlng todo with your dialog =?

Comment: Hi Dreamweiver, I can add the jQuery dialog on my street view. But While dragging(pov changed) the street view, our dialog do not move with them. Exact need is I want to set/fix the position of our dialog.